# Passing libjars in sqoop job

Tags: sqoop, sqoop2

I need to pass libjars in Sqoop import but it failed with "ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: libjars"

My Sqoop command is:

> sqoop job --create myjob -- import 
>   -libjars /var/lib/sqoop/db2jcc4.jar,/var/lib/sqoop/db2jcc.jar
>   - Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/xyz/db2/db2_password.jceks
>   --driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --connect jdbc:db2://server:3714/XYX --username user --password-alias
>   db2.password.alias --table db.table_name --fields-terminated-by '\001'
>   --null-string '\N' --delete-target-dir --target-dir /user/jainm2/test_data1 -split-by "col_name" -m 3 --delete-target-dir
>   --incremental append --last-value "2005-02-14 16:23:25"

Answer (score 0):

As per Sqoop document generic arguments should be provided next to `sqoop job`,

```
sqoop job (generic-args) (job-args) [-- [subtool-name] (subtool-args)]
```

Try in this way and let me know if it works fine.